# PHP Posting Content and Not URL Encoding

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that I am using to post a hidden input value that contains HTML. When I grab the posting Variable using $_POST it URL Encodes the data. This information is getting written to a file and needs to maintain its original values.

I have tried changing the enctype to enctype="multipart/form-data" and still no dice.

Essentially I am posting HTML that the user has edited in a hidden input then writing the modified content to a file on the server and need the original untainted content!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to url decode that field before saving it, although it is supposed to decode automatically.

```
urldecode($string)
```

For more:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php